# Azure application gateway pfx certificate installation with Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

I am trying to provision an Azure application gateway using Ansible. But am getting the below error when I try to include a PFX certificate.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>, original message: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1: invalid start byte"}
```

This is my ansible script

```
ssl_certificates:
     - data: "{{ lookup('file', './certificate.pfx') }}"
       name: certificate
       password: "xxxxxxxx"
```

I have tried the following format but no luck

- data: "{{ b64encode (lookup('file', './certificate.pfx'  )) }}"
- data: "{{ lookup('file', './certificate.pfx') | b64encode }}"
- data: "{{ lookup('file', './certificate.pfx')  b64encode }}"
- data: "{{ b64encode | (lookup('file', './certificate.pfx'  )) }}"

Comment: I am stuck with this issue, so any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Anyone know about this, am also looking for an answer.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but I found this useful https://icodealot.com/convert-data-to-base64-in-nodejs/